# Pandas dataframe groupby and transpose without sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df1) with following data:

```
Column_name                    Column_value

Id                             null
ChangeTypeCd                   null
AdditionalRef                  null
PolicyNumber                   000000836
PolicyNumber                   000000938
PolicyNumber                   000000842
PolicyVersion                  24
PolicyVersion                  48
PolicyVersion                  8
ProductCd_Desc                 null
ProductCd_name                 null
```

I am doing a groupby Column_name and transposing the data:

```
df2=df1.groupby('Column_name')['Column_value'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()
```

I am getting an extra column with Nan with the column_name sorted:

```
Column_name    0          1          2          3   

AdditionalRef  null       Nan        Nan        Nan
ChangeTypeCd   null       Nan        Nan        Nan
Id             null       Nan        Nan        Nan            
PolicyNumber   000000836  000000938  000000842  Nan
PolicyVersion  24         48         8          Nan
ProductCd_Desc null       Nan        Nan        Nan
ProductCd_name null       Nan        Nan        Nan
```

I am not sure why I am getting the column with index 3.
Also, I want my output to be in the same order as my input. Because I need to populate this data into a hive table so the order of columns is very important to me. (I will be again doing a transpose on the above data before populating into a table)

Comment: cant reproduce, tried with `df1.groupby('Column_name')['Column_value'].apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()` which works fine

Comment: Unless you say how we can produce a dataframe exhibiting the problem, it cannot be reproduced. For that reason, the question is off topic.

Comment: For the ordering part, it is enough to add `sort=False` in groupby...